# What's wrong with my pressure washer?

Tags: repair, water-pump, small-engine

Sorry if this is off topic. I couldn't find another StackExchange forum it would fit any better with.

I have a gas powered Troy Bilt (model 01902) pressure washer with a 6.5 HP Briggs & Stratton engine. When I try to start it, it is very difficult to pull the cord. I always hook up the hose to it before starting, turn on the water, and let any air pockets out before starting it. I have found that if I squeeze the trigger to spray water, then it is easier to pull. It starts normally. The engine runs poorly though and it vibrates a lot. If I stop squeezing the trigger to let the water out then the engine quits immediately.

Any ideas on what is wrong and how to fix it?

Answer (score 2):

Sounds like the pressure override in the pump itself is broke or malfunctioning. In the pump, there is a valve which will, when pressure gets to high, allow the pump to bypass itself. This allows the motor to keep running when you have released the lever and while you are starting it. Fixing it may be another story, as who knows if any of them are serviceable or not. In most cases, if you take it to a repair shop, it will probably cost you more to get it fixed than it would to replace the entire thing for a new pressure washer.